# Find out which application pool project service application is running

Tags: project-server, service-application, application-pool

How do I find out which application pool as well as the managed account my project service application is running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have to access the SharePoint Server then run the below powershell.

```
Get-SPServiceApplicationPool | Select Name, ID, ProcessAccountName
```

This will list Name of the App pool, ID of the AppPool and Account under which it is running.

Try this script

```
Get-SPServiceApplication | Select Name, @{Name="SPAppPoolName"; Expression={$_.ApplicationPool.Name}},  @{Name="IISAppPoolName"; Expression={$_.ApplicationPool.Id}}, @{Name="ProcessAccountName"; Expression={$_.ApplicationPool.ProcessAccountName}}
```

It will list Service App name( the name you mentioned when created the Service app, you can check the central admin > application management > Manager Service application), App Pool name, etc.

Comment: OK, but which one is mapped to my project service application? after running the above command I only get a listing of the application pools in a nice table format.

Comment: check the updated anwser

Comment: now I have all the info I need. clear instructions Sharepoint Guru!